# how to match HTML <Select> control option values with a string(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the html

```
<select class='navbar-select'id='sheets'>
    <option value="Folder1/sheet001.html">LimitControlTesting</option>
    <option value="Folder4/sheet002.html">NumericControlDbValueTestig</option>
    <option value="Folder122/sheet003.html">All Controls</option>
</select>
```

and here I have a string to be matched with `<option>` values

```
var mText = "sheet002.html";
```

what I want is to write a function which matches all `<option>` values with `mText` and select the option which contains `mText` in it.

like for current case

```
<option value="Folder4/sheet002.html">NumericControlDbValueTestig</option>
```

option must be selected as `mText=sheet002.html` and  above option's value contains `sheet002.html`

something like

```
for each option in #select
if(option.val contains mText)
{
select matched value option
}
```

Comment: simply using sheets.value="Folder4/sheet002.html"; works: no need to loop... (cool huh?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by fixing your HTML -- the `class` and `id` attributes are running into each other:

```
<select class="navbar-select" id="sheets">
    <option value="Folder1/sheet001.html">LimitControlTesting</option>
    <option value="Folder4/sheet002.html">NumericControlDbValueTestig</option>
    <option value="Folder122/sheet003.html">All Controls</option>
</select>
```

Then what you need is:

```
var mText = "sheet002.html";
$('#sheets option').filter(function() {
    return this.value.indexOf( mText ) > -1;
})
.prop('selected', true);
```

```js
var mText = "sheet002.html";
$('#sheets option').filter(function() {
    return this.value.indexOf( mText ) > -1;
})
.prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="navbar-select" id="sheets">
    <option value="Folder1/sheet001.html">LimitControlTesting</option>
    <option value="Folder4/sheet002.html">NumericControlDbValueTestig</option>
    <option value="Folder122/sheet003.html">All Controls</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
$('#sheets option').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('value')==mText){
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute contains selector to get required option.then you can set it selected using `.attr('selected', 'selected')`:

```
$("#sheets option[value*='"+mText +"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```